# SSO with identityserver4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, single-sign-on, identityserver4

I have to implement SSO with identitiserver4 (OAuth server).
I'm quite about authentication standards so before start working on it I make some research over the internet and I discovered that SSO is basically a social login where the provider is not a social network.

I read that identityserver4 implements **oidc** with which use the SSO.

In the *Startup.cs* file I added this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    //options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.Authority = "<url-sso-server>";
                    options.ClientId = "<client-id>";
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                });
```

Is this settings enough? Whenever I will have to add a new SSO provider I just have to ask them for their *url* and *clientId* ? Of course, they will have to whitelist my redirect url */signin-oidc*

Besides this I'm having trouble intercepting the redirect callback, I can't read any provider info:

```
var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (info == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
}
```

This always provide a null info.
Any advice?

Comment: I discovered that removing the command 'JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();' will allow to retrive the external login info